# Does anyone know why in Oxidized GUI, in the diffs it doesn't show the users who made the changes to the config?

Tags: centos

Can someone help me? I've installed oxidized on Centos 8, and I've managed to make it work with a local git repository. It retrieves configs from a virtual router csr-1000v (with ios-xe image), and it shows the diffs from one change to the router config to another. The problem is it doesn't show which users made the actual changes. It is missing the messages in the form of : Last configuration updated by username at ....".